How to get the token account in Solana?
I am trying to get token account for this.
 #[account(mut)]
    pub nft_info: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

I used getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(), but there is an error.
Error: AnchorError caused by account: nft_info. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized. 

Additionally, when the NFT minted, the token account is generated, isn't it?
Fully understanding about the token account.
